# Rails acts_as_taggable heroku 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, controller, acts-as-taggable-on

I've created a new Projects model for my application and everything works fine in development but in production on Heroku I receive a 500 error. The error is coming from my ProjectsController#create the error states:

```
2014-05-16T07:00:48.018827+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-16T07:00:48.018832+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG:
:UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" does not exist
2014-05-16T07:00:48.018834+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings
_count" = COALESCE("taggings_coun...
2014-05-16T07:00:48.018835+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Which is almost the exact same error as the one in this issue that I found after some searching: https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit/issues/57. This person said they solved it by pulling these new migrations from acts_as_taggable https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/tree/master/db/migrate

I'm fairly certain that I have the same problem but I'm new to rails and not sure what he means by he pulled those migrations. Do I just update my acts_as_taggable gem and push to heroku? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to only occur when the model attribute is called 'tags', it causing some sort of conflict but only in production. Dropping the column and creating a new one with a different name worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new (welcome btw!!!), here's your error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "taggings_count" does not exist
```

This is a standard error, basically meaning **you don't have that column in your db**

Your `acts_as_taggable` is looking for the `taggings_count` column in your *production* db, and it's not there. A simple fix is to use the [`rake db:migrate`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations) method in your production environment (Heroku):

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

This wil run the migrate method on your heroku instance, which *should* populate the db for you. This is exclusive of any bugs/errors `acts-as-taggable` may have

---

**Error**

In regards to the specifics of your error, the link you gave basically says the newest version of `acts-as-taggable` has introduced several migrations, which your app will not have included

The way to fix they recommended was to take the migration files as defined [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/tree/master/db/migrate), and put them into their `db/migrate` directory -- allowing you to populate your db correctly

If you need help with this (after trying `rake db:migrate`), comment & I'll give you some more info

Comment: I've tried migrating multiple times and it's still throwing the error. Could you give me more info on the other fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just rollback and migrate again:

```
heroku run rake db:rollback STEP=5
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

STEP=5 because acts_as_taggable creates 5 migrations